# Between operator not working in my code

Tags: php, mysql, database, date, mysqli

Between operator not working in my code. Please help me

```
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
    $today = date("m/d/y");
    $newdate = strtotime ( '-7 day' , strtotime ( $today ) ) ;
    $newdate = date ( 'm/d/y' , $newdate );  

    $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM service_calls WHERE open_date BETWEEN '$today' AND '$newdate'" );
```

It is giving me blank window after running this code.

I  have open_date with format same as mentioned above.

Comment: Try using dates in international format: `Y-m-d`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because in your database the date is in `Y-m-d` format, use this

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
$today = date("Y-m-d");
$newdate = strtotime ( '-7 day' , strtotime ( $today ) ) ;
$newdate = date ( 'Y-m-d' , $newdate );
```

Answer (score 1):

First - on [blank pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php/12772851#12772851) in general
Second - on [mysqli errors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15447204/285587) in particular
Third - you have to use [proper Mysql date format](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html) (which is `Y-m-d`) in your table and queries

finally, you don't need PHP for such a query

```
SELECT * FROM service_calls 
    WHERE open_date BETWEEN CURDATE() AND CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY;
```