# Unable to execute() query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to get data from a MySQL database and I get:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object in Line 79...

on this line:

```
$stmt->execute();
```

I'm just trying to get this:  [image]

and more specifically the `left` data cell (very right of pic) that is an `int(5)`.

Here's what I have:

```
$query = "SELECT left FROM members WHERE id=$uid";

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query); 

    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($left);
    $stmt->fetch();
    echo "Left: $left";
    $stmt->close();
```

Funny thing is, when I change `SELECT left` to something like `SELECT username`, I get the username cell back as expected, but for `left` I get the error.

Comment: Why not to use search first? [Mysqli update throwing Call to a member function bind_param() error](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15447204/285587)

Comment: and then http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html

Comment: yep this ^ beat me to it.. put single quotes around left

Comment: and of course SQL injection at it's best

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add quotes:

```
SELECT `left` FROM `members` WHERE id=$uid
```

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
$query = "SELECT `left` FROM members WHERE id=$uid";
```

to avoid reserved keyword problem.

Edit:

Including comment from Your Common Sense to link

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html