# Error boolean given in... MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Plz Help i Dont know what is wrong in this function ....

```
$gsql = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE group='$group_name' ORDER BY postdate DESC LIMIT 0,20";
$gquery = mysqli_query($db_conx, $gsql);
$gstatusnumrows = mysqli_num_rows($gquery);

while ($grow = mysqli_fetch_array($gquery, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
```

and it keeps saying this error :-

```
Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in D:\group.php on line 3

Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in D:\group.php on line 5
```

Comment: It means that the query that you are executing fails.

Comment: `boolean given` means the call to `mysqli_query` returned **FALSE**. That could be because the SQL query contains errors - the column `group` is a defined word and should be escaped: `\`group\``.

Comment: @shadyyx No, a SELECT query that returns no rows returns an empty result set, not a boolean.

Comment: is the variable $group_name defined?

Comment: @Kolink Yep, I realized that and modified the comment ;-) Thanks.

Comment: i changed my cloumn name to 'groupname' and it worked thanks for help :)

Comment: [Mysqli update throwing Call to a member function bind_param() error](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15447204/285587)

Answer (score 5):

That means your query failed.

> [[`mysqli_query`](http://php.net/mysqli-query)] returns `FALSE` on failure. For successful `SELECT`, `SHOW`, `DESCRIBE` or `EXPLAIN` queries `mysqli_query()` will return a `mysqli_result` object. For other successful queries `mysqli_query()` will return `TRUE`.

So use [`mysqli_error`](http://php.net/mysqli-error) to find out what you did wrong. In this case, though, it's because you have a column named "group". `GROUP` is a reserved word in MySQL. To be on the safe side, ALL database, table and column names SHOULD be enclosed in backticks `` ` `` to prevent any possible ambiguity.

Comment: Another way to avoid ambiguity which does not require the use of backticks is to qualify all column references with a table name or (preferably) a table alias, e.g. `SELECT p.* FROM posts p WHERE p.group = ... ORDER BY p.postdate ... `. This has the additional benefit (when more than one table is referenced), of avoiding ambiguous column references.

Comment: thanks alot for your help i changed my column name in my database and it worked thanks a lot :)