# MySQL error. Works locally but not remotelly

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have this code

```
$savechanges = $dataserver->prepare("UPDATE hub_apps SET aname=?, aicon=?, aimage=?, atype=?, aurl=? WHERE id = ?");
$savechanges->bind_param('sssisi',
$_POST['app_name'],
$_POST['app_icon'],
$_POST['app_screen'],
$_POST['app_type'],
$_POST['app_url'],
$_GET['id']);
$savechanges->execute();
$savechanges->close();
```

It runs on my local server but online it fails with:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object

on the `bind_param` line.

Am I missing something?

**UPDATE:**
Well I followed user "Your Common Sense" link and added "or trigger_error($dataserver->error)".
Turns out user didn't had UPDATE privileges. Thanks for the help :) My mistake. :X

Comment: It seems that `prepare` is not working

Comment: check if the dll of mysqli is enabled. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.installation.php

Comment: [Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15447204/285587)

Comment: It is enabled. I can do INSERT it works flawlessly, this on the other hand, fails and it's weird.

Comment: Well I followed Your Common Sense's link and added "or trigger_error($dataserver->error)"

Turns out user does not have UPDATE privileges. Thanks for the help :)

My mistake. :X