# digit in mysqli query returns data but a string does not

Tags: mysqli

so I did a multi filter search in mysqli where you can search using textbox, collection id or type id.

The problem is that when using the search textbox, it returns a

```
Call to a member function fetch_object() on boolean
```

**But it only returns that error when I type in a string or a single letter. When I type in a digit such as 1 or 2, it works perfectly fine and brings the correct result.** 
Thanks

```
`
     $whereClauses = array();
   if (! empty($_POST['search'])) $whereClauses[] =       'tblfurniture.product_name ='.'%'.mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['search']).'%';
if (! empty($_POST['collection'])) $whereClauses[] ='tblfurniture.COLID='.mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['collection']);
if (! empty($_POST['type'])) $whereClauses[] = 'tblfurniture.TYPID='.mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['type']);
```

```
    $where = '';
     if (count($whereClauses) > 0) {
$where = 'WHERE '.implode(' AND ',$whereClauses);
```

}
$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM tblfurniture JOIN      tblcollection ON tblfurniture.COLID = tblcollection.COLID ".$where);

}

```
     else {
 $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'hezefurniture');
     // Check connection
   if (!$conn) {
die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
  $results = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM tblfurniture
```

JOIN tblcollection ON tblfurniture.COLID = tblcollection.COLID 
ORDER BY  tblfurniture.product_id");

}
     while($row = $results->fetch_object())
        {`

Comment: Wow - fix your layout and put a little bit of effort in it. Nobody will read this.

Comment: sorry about that its my first post, and was in hurry

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mysqli update throwing Call to a member function bind\_param() error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15447133/mysqli-update-throwing-call-to-a-member-function-bind-param-error)

Comment: correct me if im wrong, but my error seems to be completely different than the one you stated

Answer (score 0):

Your query is returning null value.
It seem you are executing **wrong query on search textbox** ,
use `mysqli_error()` to show error .

Comment: mysql_error() states that when inserting a string, it says that the column of that name does not exist, even though I have specified the column to be tblfurniture.product_name.

Comment: got to this stage now: Unknown column 'tblfurniture.product_name' in 'where clause'

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:

in

```
 if (! empty($_POST['search'])) $whereClauses[] = 'tblfurniture.product_name ='.'%'.mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['search']).'%';
```

should be

```
 if (! empty($_POST['search'])) $whereClauses[] = "tblfurniture.product_name ='%".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['search'])."%'";
```